# Constructor using multiple arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, constructor

Having trouble creating a constructor that takes multiple one dimensional arrays of `String`s:

```
class relation {

String[] setA, setB, setC;

relation (String[] setA, String[] setB, String[] setC) {
    this.setA = setA;
    this.setB = setB;
    this.setC = setC;
} 
}

public class matrix {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    relation relation1 = new relation({"1","2","3","4","5"}, {"1","2","3","4"}, {"2","3","4","5"});
    relation relation2 = new relation({"a","b","c","d"}, {"a","b","c","d","b","c"}, {"a","b","c","d","c","b"});

}

}
```

I keep getting multiple errors
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to 
     relation
    - Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
    - Syntax error on token ")", } expected

I need to be able to use each array separately withing the relation class.

Comment: It's off-topic here, but normally, in java, we write class names in CamelCase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use array literals that way in Java - you have to explicitly initialize them. e.g.:

```
relation relation1 = new relation(new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5"}, 
                                  new String[]{"1","2","3","4"},
                                  new String[]{"2","3","4","5"});
```

Comment: Note that `String []arr = {"1","2"};` is still allowed.

Comment: @ChetanKinger yup, but that's the only place it'll fly

Comment: @Mureinik True. The compiler replaces it with `String []arr = new String[]{"1","2"};` I wonder why the limitation was imposed on using the same shorthand for arguments. Also, I prefer using varargs over an array as a parameter in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this -

```
class Relation {
    String[] setA, setB, setC;
    Relation(String[] setA, String[] setB, String[] setC) {
        this.setA = setA;
        this.setB = setB;
        this.setC = setC;
    }
}

public class Assignment3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Relation relation1 = new Relation(
                new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, new String[]{"1", "2",
                        "3", "4"}, new String[]{"2", "3", "4", "5"});
        Relation relation2 = new Relation(new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"},
                new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "c"}, new String[]{"a",
                        "b", "c", "d", "c", "b"});
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely formatted. Other than that, does not add much value over the accepted answer. Especially when it is posted 7 minutes later..

Comment: Yes - agree nicely fomatted and follow Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this it will work

```
relation relation1 = new relation(new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5"},
                        new String[]{"1","2","3","4"},new String[]{"2","3","4","5"});
```